# HI all i am working on apex 19.1 getting some error while creating classic report

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

HI all i am working on apex 19.1 getting some error while creating classic report that while executing below block,

```
declare
vquery varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   if 
(:P3_POSTCODE is not null
           and
           :P3_HUISNR is not null
           )
      then
      vquery :='SELECT * FROM LVV_AANSLUITPUNT where lvv_aansluitpunt.la_post_code = :P3_POSTCODE 
          and lvv_aansluitpunt.la_huis_nr = :P3_HUISNR and ((lvv_aansluitpunt.la_dat_aanvang is not null 
          and lvv_aansluitpunt.la_dat_eind is null ) or (lvv_aansluitpunt.la_dat_aanvang is null 
          and lvv_aansluitpunt.la_dat_eind is null )) and lvv_aansluitpunt.an_code is not null 
          and lvv_aansluitpunt.vl_id is not null 
          and not exists (select '*' from lvv_juridische_lever jl where jl.vv_id = lvv_aansluitpunt.vv_id and upper(jl.nv_code) ="B")
          and exists (select '*' from lvv_vv_leiding vl where vl.vl_id = lvv_aansluitpunt.vl_id 
          and ((vl.vl_dat_aanvang is not null and vl.vl_dat_eind is null ) or (vl.vl_dat_aanvang is null and vl.vl_dat_eind is null ))) 
          and exists (select '*' from lvv_vaste_verbinding vv , lvv_soort_artikel sa where vv.vv_id = lvv_aansluitpunt.vv_id and vv.sa_code = sa.sa_code and sa.sa_aansl_drager_j_n = "J")';


      else

    vquery := 'select distinct sa.sa_code
       ,      sa.sa_type_verbinding
       ,      vv.vv_id
       ,      nvl(vv.vv_lijnbenaming_nw,vv.vv_lijnbenaming)
       ,      vl.vl_id
       ,      vl.vl_lijnbenaming

       from   lvv_soort_artikel      sa
       ,      lvv_vv_leiding         vl
       ,      lvv_juridische_lever   jl
       ,      lvv_ldm_aansluitpunt   la
       ,      lvv_vaste_verbinding   vv
       where  :P3_VV_LIJNBEN =
       nvl(vv.vv_lijnbenaming_nw,vv.vv_lijnbenaming)
       and    vv.vv_id                         = vl.vv_id
       and    vv.vv_id                         = jl.vv_id
       and    vv.vv_id                         = la.vv_id
       and    vv.sa_code                       = sa.sa_code
       and    la.an_code          is not null
       and    vl.vl_id            is not null
       and    jl.nv_code                        <> "B"
       and    sa.sa_aansl_drager_j_n            =  "j"
       and   ((la.la_dat_aanvang is not null
               and
               la.la_dat_eind    is null
              )
              or
              (la.la_dat_aanvang is null
              and
               la.la_dat_eind     is null
              ))
       and    ((vl.vl_dat_aanvang is not null
                and
                vl.vl_dat_eind is null
               )
               or
               (vl.vl_dat_aanvang is null
                and
                vl.vl_dat_eind is null
              ))';

      end if ;

      RETURN vquery;

    end;
```

Error returned on execution is :- ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!

ORA-06550: line 24, column 40: ORA-00904: "j": invalid identifier

".

Comment: Please do not put the entire content of your question in the title. Explain it in the body of the post, and ask a specific question in that post. Also, please make an effort to format your code properly; you can get formatting help by clicking the `?` toolbar button at the top right corner of the text area where you're writing your question. Please [edit] to address thesse issues. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sanatan, did you still need help with this or did VN'sCorner's answer help?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle single quotes are used for string literals. Double quotes are used for tablename/columnnames.

Replace double quotes for literal 'j' in query with single quotes.If the string vquery has line breaks then each line should be enclosed in string and has to be concatenated together.

```
 else

vquery := 'select distinct sa.sa_code '||chr(10)||
   ',      sa.sa_type_verbinding '||chr(10)||
   ',      vv.vv_id '||chr(10)||
   ',      nvl(vv.vv_lijnbenaming_nw,vv.vv_lijnbenaming) '||chr(10)||
   ',      vl.vl_id '||chr(10)||
   ',      vl.vl_lijnbenaming '||chr(10)||

  ' from   lvv_soort_artikel      sa '||chr(10)||
  ' ,      lvv_vv_leiding         vl '||chr(10)||
  ' ,      lvv_juridische_lever   jl '||chr(10)||
  ' ,      lvv_ldm_aansluitpunt   la '||chr(10)||
```

To escape single quotes for String literals,use two single quotes instead of one,like below:

```
   'and    jl.nv_code                        <> ''B'''||chr(10)||
   'and    sa.sa_aansl_drager_j_n            =  ''j'''||chr(10)||
```